# Socket.io emits but does not trigger listener

Tags: java, android, socket.io

I can connect to the socket for implementing group chat application in android, but when I emit a custom event (`chat_in_group`), it never triggers my listener. but I can see on my server that it was a successful emit because the data is saved in server.

I have tried various ways to fix this problem but it won't trigger my `emit` listener. It should receive a JSON object.

Does somebody have any idea whats going wrong?

```
      mSocket.emit("event_chat_in_group", messageSendJson.toString());

      mSocket.on("group_online_message", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            Log.d("response",":)"+args);
        }
    });
```

i am trying to catch this event from server ..

```
io.of(‘myNamespace’).to(‘room’).emit(‘group_online_message’, ‘message’);
```

Comment: can you post full code? Also you may need to implement listener before the emit method

Answer (score 0):

try calling this

// your one by one value add in array not json

String[] array = new String[]{id,message, type};

mSocket.emit(WebFields.SEND_MSG, array);

Comment: emit does work , data is receive by server properly but on server end when the event is fire back to give me response i m not able to get it through listener.

Comment: @DeepikaSingh have you get the solution? same issue I am facing.